# Simulating JavaScript extension functions

Tags: php

I was wondering if I can, in PHP, like JavaScript, apply a function call to the return of an object. In JavaScript I can do this:

```
var y = 1;
var x = y.toString().concat(' + 1');
console.log(x);
```

And I think if it is possible to do almost the same in PHP. I was thinking in recursion to this and I didn't know exactly the name to search for it. I'm trying, in the moment:

```
<?php
    class Main {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->Main = new Main;
        }

        public function merge(/* this */ $xs, $ys) {
            return array_merge($xs, $ys);
        }

        public function add(/* this */ $xs, $ys) {
            return array_push($xs, $ys);
        }
    }

    $aux = new Main;
    $x = $aux   -> merge([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
                -> add(7)
                -> add(8)
                -> add(9);
    // $x => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
?>
```

This is overflowing everything. I receive an overflow message:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached
```

Am I able to do this, like in JavaScript? Almost the same as C# extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called method chaining:

```
class Main {
    private $ar = array();

    public function merge($xs, $ys) {
        $this->ar = array_merge($xs, $ys);
        return $this;
    }

    public function add($ys) {
        $this->ar[]= $ys;
        return $this;
    }


    public function toArray(){
        return $this->ar;
    }

    //if you want to echo a string representation
    public function __toString(){
        return implode(',', $this-ar);
    }
}
$aux = new Main;
$x = $aux->merge([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])->add(7)->add(8)-> add(9);
echo $x;
var_dump($x->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the returns from functions, but it’s not as nice-looking as JavaScript:

```
<?php

$array1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$array2 = array(4, 5, 6);

$x = array_push(array_push(array_push(array_merge($array1, $array2), 7), 8), 9);
```

`$x` should then be an array containing the numbers 1 through 9.